# Don't let the parent website, get info from my iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have to make an iFrame that will manage user's sensible information. I need the parent page not to be able to get information from it. What can you recommend me to achieve this goal?. I already saw how to obfuscate my javascript code, but its not enough I need to be impossible to have access from the website to some iFrame's values that are inside some fields that the user will fill up.

For example I try making my own frame and web to test the security and if I put this on the web:
iFrameName.document.getElementById("idTextField").value;
I get the text that the client filled, thats what I want to prevent, to be impossible (or very difficult) for the web to get the data of the fields I have in my iFrame.

Thank you all.

By the way Im using HTML, JS and PHP

Comment: If the parent page is from a different domain, it's already impossible for it to get to the iframe content.

Comment: but see the example I just put on the question. I dont know why that keeps working if its impossible to get information. 
Thank you

Comment: You example involved two URLs from the same domain. The browser will allow that because it assumes that it's OK.  When your iframe is in a page from a *different* URL, then the browser won't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy

Because of Same Origin policy in Javascript, from javascript is impossible to have access to an iFrame if both (parent and iFrame) are located in different domains.

"So, iframe.contentWindow.document will be the inner document.
You can access it or modify from parent window if both iframe and the parent come from one domain/host/port (security limitations are discussed more in detail in the next sections)." 
Text From: http://javascript.info/tutorial/frames-and-iframes

Answer (score 3):

All modern browsers prevent a site from getting iframe content that doesn't belong to it. This is a security feature to prevent hacking.

For example, if you log into your bank's website and then go to another site that includes your bank in an iframe, then you may see the bank page in an iframe, but the third party site will still not be able to read it.

Furthermore, your bank will probably not even appear in the frame to begin with because many sites (including StackOverflow) [prevent iframes from displaying them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

Assuming your iframe isn't in the same domain as the containing app and it doesn't need to communicate with with the other app, then you don't need to do anything special.

If you *do* need to communicate between windows/frames in different domains, then you can use the [`window.postMessage()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to pass data between them. The API will allow you to decide *how* you use the messages while retaining control of your page. (Protip: Don't `eval` the passed messages.)

Comment: I always wondered, this only stops the "easy" way of stealing data, if you just make your own browser-type application request the data, you'd still get the data, as the browser is the thing that decides to stop the data retrieval.

Comment: So you say that if for example they my iFrame with this code, inside of their pages they cannot get values of fields that I have inside of the iFrame?
<form action="" method="POST">
    <script
      src="https://mypage.com/iFrame.js"
      data-key="password"
      data-token="tokengiventothepage">
    </script>
</form>

Yes I need to communicate with them but for that I've seen the "Secure Cross Domain iFrame Communication", that I think will solve this problem
http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/

Comment: @user2540080 If I understand the question, you're talking about something different. If you presume that a malicious agent can put arbitrary content on your page, then you have no control over what happens. Make sure that any dynamic content is sanitized.

As for your secure communication, it looks like the library you posted hasn't been tested in newer browsers. I would see if you can get this working instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @pathurs Yes, but to take advantage of that, a hacker would have to convince someone to download a fake browser and log-in to a secure site with it. At that point there would be no advantage to violating cross-domain policy.